# How to send a notification for a particular android device by GCM through Windows azure?

Tags: android, windows, azure, google-cloud-messaging

I had registered android device by GCM and registration id of device is registered with Windows azure which gives an another unique id for that device. Now my doubt is how to send notification to only one device by the registration id given by windows azure(not by GCM registration id)? I was referred the following link.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn223273.aspx

URL specified as follows in that link. Here i know namespace,Notification hub and messages but where i have to give that unique registration id of device given by windows azure for sending notification to that device

```
https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{NotificationHub}/messages/?api-version=2013-08
```

I had used the following code in java

```
String strAzureURL = "https://namespaceName.servicebus.windows.net/hubName/testMessage";

                          String strAzureRegistrationId = "Tag1";

                    String strSharedAccessSignature = "MySharedAccessSignature";
                    String strSharedAccessName = "MySharedAccessName";
                    String strAuthorizationToken = URLDecoder.decode(strSharedAccessName+":"+strSharedAccessSignature,"UTF-8");

                    String strAuthWrapFormat = "WRAP access_token=\""+strAuthorizationToken+"\"";

                    String info = null;
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    try {
                        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(strAzureURL);
                        method.setRequestHeader("Authorization", strAuthWrapFormat);

                        method.setRequestHeader("ServiceBusNotification-Tags", strAzureRegistrationId);
                        method.setRequestHeader("ServiceBusNotification-Format", "gcm");
                        method.setRequestHeader("Audience","https://namespaceName.servicebus.windows.net");
                        client.executeMethod(method);
                        info = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
                        System.out.println("Response "+info);
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    throw e1;
}
```

Now i am receiving the following error.

```
    Response <Error><Code>401</Code>

<Detail>MissingAudience: The provided token does not specify the 'Audience'..TrackingId:75c1d492-3ddf-4d88-84b7-1c2f07d9623b_G5,TimeStamp:1/8/2014 9:57:39 AM</Detail>

</Error>
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282661.aspx.  It includes all of the steps for registering your client application with GCM and then with Notification Hubs.  From the client side, it registers with the Notification Hub and set's it's "MyTag" to to be the Tag.  What you'll want to do is register with a tag set to the registration ID.  So from the client side:

```
hub.register(registrationId, registrationId, <Optional Other Tags>);
```

Then from wherever you're triggering the push notification, you would pass in the registration ID you want to deliver to as the ServiceBusNotification-Tags (as seen in the REST API link you provided).  That will then cause the Notification Hub to deliver a message to only devices that have registered with the tag.

Comment: Thank you so much.Link has server code for C# application. But i want to send notification for particular device from java application. How to do it? My doubt is in Server side code of java.

Comment: There is no Java side SDK for Notification Hubs so you'll have to make a call to the REST API for Notification Hubs with Java.  Per the link you provided, make a POST to the endpoint and in the ServiceBusNotification-Tags, send the registration ID of the device you want to deliver to.

Comment: I had used REST calls but i don't know where to pass that particular registration id in windows azure URL. Can you please check the updated question?

Comment: Check out the documentation at the URL you reference.  It includes the REQUEST HEADERS section which includes ServiceBusNotification-Tags.  You can pass the registration ID in as the tag.  You'll need to register with the Hub using the device's registration ID as a tag (as I mentioned in the answer above).  Once you register with the reg ID as a tag, any pushes to that tag will push down to that device.

Comment: I tried with tag but now i am receiving some error related to "Audience".Can you please check updated question and guide me.Thanks

Comment: I just published a git repo with a Java rest wrapper for Notification Hubs. You can use that code directly https://github.com/fsautomata/notificationhubs-rest-java